# Hadoop JAR command - Setting java.library.path

Tags: hadoop, classpath

I'm trying to run a java program on Hadoop cluster. Here's the command-

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/lib/*:/home/rgupta/bdAnalytics/lib/*
hadoop jar $jarpath bigdat.twitter.queue.TweetOMQSub >  $logsFldr/subsHdpOMQ_$1.log 2>&1 &
#java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath  class/:lib/:lib/jzmq-2.1.3.jar  bigdat.twitter.queue.TweetOMQSub > log/subsFilterOMQ_$1.log 2>&1 &
```

---

This throws following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
```

If I use the Java native command above, it works fine. Also, the hadoop node where I m trying to test it, does have the necessary jzmq jars under /usr/local/lib directory. Is there a way I can set java.library.path to Hadoop JAR command.
Please suggest how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

sorry misread your question so editing:

you should be able to use the [libjars](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/) option

In your case:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/lib/:/home/rgupta/bdAnalytics/lib/

hadoop jar $jarpath bigdat.twitter.queue.TweetOMQSub -libjars /usr/local/lib ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this out, but no luck! I still get the same exception

Answer (score 1):

Try `export HADOOP_OPTS=$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib`

and export other jars the usual way you are doing before running a job - using  HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey check it now, I had a minor typo, I missed $ before HADOOP_OPTS